# Editing a running docker container

Tags: docker, ssh, pycharm, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I need to edit a running docker container files that are inside a remote server (Linux) from my local development environment(Windows).

How should I do that? Using a editor tool or a IDE?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please add a bit more information to your post regarding why you want to edit the files in a container. If at all possible I would recommend stopping the container and building a new image with the desired changes.

Comment: I find the question not very clear, I added an answer, but if you meant something else, please edit the question and I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: To get an additional shell into the running container, you can try using docker exec -it <img> bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the question not very clear, but if what you want is **editing the parameters of a running container**, you can **NOT** edit a running container parameters (except of some very little amount of parameters using `docker update`, but normally they are not very useful).

The best you can do is commiting the container and then rerun it again. You can check the link, if that is what you want I can explain more about that.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

If you really mean **editing the files inside the container**, I don't understand exactly where is your problem in that, as it should not be a problem (you can use `docker copy` or transfering files using `scp`, etc...).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

You may edit your question and give more infos, and I will edit my answer depending on that.

Comment: There is a Web application built on top o Django. This application is using Docker version running on Ubuntu server. I need to customize the layout of this application. 

I have a windows local machine that I use to development. I am able to connect the docker remote server(Ubuntu) using Putty tool and also I am able to access the docker inside this remote server and edit all files inside there (.html, .css, .py, etc). But what I need is a editor like sublime text that allow me to make change directly inside the container.

I do not know if I could be clearer.  ^^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should explain exactly what you are trying to do here. From what I understand you are looking to develop a Django Application, that is running in a remote Docker Container from your local Windows machine. Is that right?

If so: You can define a remote interpreter which mounts your local files to a Docker Container and runs it there. Look at [this tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/), specific for Django or the [PyCharm Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-docker.html) on that topic.

Otherwise, if you actually want to edit files in a running Docker Container from within the command line, I guess the easiest way is to use vim, which is either preinstalled, then you can access the files via `vim <filename>` or you can install it by updating the Dockerfile (or temporarily via `apt-get`). Running an Editor or IDE with a graphical user interface from within a Container requires more work, if possible at all in your case.

Is that about what you were looking for?